# Java HashMap Did Not Return Expected Result when put the data

Tags: java

Hi i want to ask about java hashmap this is my code

```
     HashMap<String, Object> hash_map = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 

        // Mapping string values to int keys 
        hash_map.put("SP", "A"); 
        hash_map.put("C1", "B"); 
        hash_map.put("C2", "C"); 

        //hash_map.put("C3", "You"); 

        // Displaying the HashMap 
        System.out.println("Initial Mappings are: " + hash_map); 

        // Inserting existing key along with new value 

        hash_map.put("C3", "D"); 
        hash_map.put("C4", "E"); 
        System.out.println("New map is: " + hash_map);
```

this result

> > Initial Mappings are: {SP=A, C1=B, C2=C}
> >
> > New map is: {C3=D, C4=E, SP=A, C1=B, C2=C}

my expected result

> > Initial Mappings are: {SP=A, C1=B, C2=C}
> >
> > New map is: {SP=A, C1=B, C2=C, C3=D, C4=E}

Answer (score 3):

A [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is ordered by the `hashCode` into *buckets*. To have a `Map` that preserves insertion order, use a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). Like,

```
Map<String, Object> hash_map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

HashMap makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

If you want order use LinkedHashMap.

Please check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html for further details.